# How to get all user ids from a collection where the document not present in another collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, lookup

col1 :

```
{
 "uuid" : "aaa"
}
{
 "uuid" : "bbb"
}
{
 "uuid" : "ccc"
}
```

col2 :

```
{
 "uuid" : "aaa"
 "offer_id" : "offer_id"
}
```

I need a query to get all UUID from col1 where the UUID wont present with specific offer id.
(offer_id will be hardcoded)

Expected Output :

```
{
 "uuids" : ["bbb","ccc"]
}
```

Comment: Please post expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
db.col1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "col2",
            let: { uuid: "$uuid" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $ne: ["$uuid", "$$uuid"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "uuids"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$uuids" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            uuids: {
                $push: "$uuid"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

output

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "uuids" : [
        "bbb",
        "ccc"
    ]
}
```